# Hybridauth Library not compatible with installed PECL OAuth extension

Tags: php, oauth, hybridauth, pecl-oauth

I try to login in my websites using Google API, in local it's working good.

but on server it's given error. error is -

> "Got An Error - Hybridauth Library not compatible with installed PECL
>   OAuth extension. Please disable it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had go for get right answer, do r&d and finally I solve my issue.
for it we need to update auth.php (lib. file)

```
<?php
/**
 * HybridAuth
 * http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net | http://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth
 * (c) 2009-2015, HybridAuth authors | http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/licenses.html
 */
/**
 * Hybrid_Auth class
 *
 * Hybrid_Auth class provide a simple way to authenticate users via OpenID and OAuth.
 *
 * Generally, Hybrid_Auth is the only class you should instanciate and use throughout your application.
 */
class Hybrid_Auth {
    public static $version = "2.7.0-dev";
    /**
     * Configuration array
     * @var array
     */
    public static $config = array();
    /**
     * Auth cache
     * @var Hybrid_Storage
     */
    public static $store = null;
    /**
     * Error pool
     * @var Hybrid_Error
     */
    public static $error = null;
    /**
     * Logger
     * @var Hybrid_Logger
     */
    public static $logger = null;
    /**
     * Try to start a new session of none then initialize Hybrid_Auth
     *
     * Hybrid_Auth constructor will require either a valid config array or
     * a path for a configuration file as parameter. To know more please
     * refer to the Configuration section:
     * http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Configuration.html
     *
     * @param array $config Configuration array or path to a configratuion file
     */
    function __construct($config) {
        Hybrid_Auth::initialize($config);
    }
    /**
     * Try to initialize Hybrid_Auth with given $config hash or file
     *
     * @param array $config Configuration array or path to a configratuion file
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static function initialize($config) {
        if (!is_array($config) && !file_exists($config)) {
            throw new Exception("Hybriauth config does not exist on the given path.", 1);
        }
        if (!is_array($config)) {
            $config = include $config;
        }
// build some need'd paths
        $config["path_base"] = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/";
        $config["path_libraries"] = $config["path_base"] . "thirdparty/";
        $config["path_resources"] = $config["path_base"] . "resources/";
        $config["path_providers"] = $config["path_base"] . "Providers/";
// reset debug mode
        if (!isset($config["debug_mode"])) {
            $config["debug_mode"] = false;
            $config["debug_file"] = null;
        }
# load hybridauth required files, a autoload is on the way...
        require_once $config["path_base"] . "Error.php";
//require_once $config["path_base"] . "Exception.php";
        require_once $config["path_base"] . "Logger.php";
        require_once $config["path_base"] . "Provider_Adapter.php";
        require_once $config["path_base"] . "Provider_Model.php";
        require_once $config["path_base"] . "Provider_Model_OpenID.php";
        require_once $config["path_base"] . "Provider_Model_OAuth1.php";
        require_once $config["path_base"] . "Provider_Model_OAuth2.php";
        require_once $config["path_base"] . "User.php";
        require_once $config["path_base"] . "User_Profile.php";
        require_once $config["path_base"] . "User_Contact.php";
        require_once $config["path_base"] . "User_Activity.php";
        if (!class_exists("Hybrid_Storage", false)) {
            require_once $config["path_base"] . "Storage.php";
        }
// hash given config
        Hybrid_Auth::$config = $config;
// instance of log mng
        Hybrid_Auth::$logger = new Hybrid_Logger();
// instance of errors mng
        Hybrid_Auth::$error = new Hybrid_Error();
// start session storage mng
        Hybrid_Auth::$store = new Hybrid_Storage();
        Hybrid_Logger::info("Enter Hybrid_Auth::initialize()");
        Hybrid_Logger::info("Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). PHP version: " . PHP_VERSION);
        Hybrid_Logger::info("Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth version: " . Hybrid_Auth::$version);
        Hybrid_Logger::info("Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth called from: " . Hybrid_Auth::getCurrentUrl());
// PHP Curl extension [http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php]
        if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
            Hybrid_Logger::error('Hybridauth Library needs the CURL PHP extension.');
            throw new Exception('Hybridauth Library needs the CURL PHP extension.');
        }
// PHP JSON extension [http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php]
        if (!function_exists('json_decode')) {
            Hybrid_Logger::error('Hybridauth Library needs the JSON PHP extension.');
            throw new Exception('Hybridauth Library needs the JSON PHP extension.');
        }
// session.name
        if (session_name() != "PHPSESSID") {
            Hybrid_Logger::info('PHP session.name diff from default PHPSESSID. http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name.');
        }
// safe_mode is on
        if (ini_get('safe_mode')) {
            Hybrid_Logger::info('PHP safe_mode is on. http://php.net/safe-mode.');
        }
// open basedir is on
        if (ini_get('open_basedir')) {
            Hybrid_Logger::info('PHP open_basedir is on. http://php.net/open-basedir.');
        }
        Hybrid_Logger::debug("Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump used config: ", serialize($config));
        Hybrid_Logger::debug("Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump current session: ", Hybrid_Auth::storage()->getSessionData());
        Hybrid_Logger::info("Hybrid_Auth initialize: check if any error is stored on the endpoint...");
        if (Hybrid_Error::hasError()) {
            $m = Hybrid_Error::getErrorMessage();
            $c = Hybrid_Error::getErrorCode();
            $p = Hybrid_Error::getErrorPrevious();
            Hybrid_Logger::error("Hybrid_Auth initialize: A stored Error found, Throw an new Exception and delete it from the store: Error#$c, '$m'");
            Hybrid_Error::clearError();
// try to provide the previous if any
// Exception::getPrevious (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0) http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getprevious.php
            if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=') && ($p instanceof Exception)) {
                throw new Exception($m, $c, $p);
            } else {
                throw new Exception($m, $c);
            }
        }
        Hybrid_Logger::info("Hybrid_Auth initialize: no error found. initialization succeed.");
    }
    /**
     * Hybrid storage system accessor
     *
     * Users sessions are stored using HybridAuth storage system ( HybridAuth 2.0 handle PHP Session only) and can be accessed directly by
     * Hybrid_Auth::storage()->get($key) to retrieves the data for the given key, or calling
     * Hybrid_Auth::storage()->set($key, $value) to store the key => $value set.
     *
     * @return Hybrid_Storage
     */
    public static function storage() {
        return Hybrid_Auth::$store;
    }
    /**
     * Get hybridauth session data
     * @return string|null
     */
    function getSessionData() {
        return Hybrid_Auth::storage()->getSessionData();
    }
    /**
     * Restore hybridauth session data
     *
     * @param string $sessiondata Serialized session data
     * @retun void
     */
    function restoreSessionData($sessiondata = null) {
        Hybrid_Auth::storage()->restoreSessionData($sessiondata);
    }
    /**
     * Try to authenticate the user with a given provider.
     *
     * If the user is already connected we just return and instance of provider adapter,
     * ELSE, try to authenticate and authorize the user with the provider.
     *
     * $params is generally an array with required info in order for this provider and HybridAuth to work,
     *  like :
     *          hauth_return_to: URL to call back after authentication is done
     *        openid_identifier: The OpenID identity provider identifier
     *           google_service: can be "Users" for Google user accounts service or "Apps" for Google hosted Apps
     *
     * @param string $providerId ID of the provider
     * @param array  $params      Params
     * @return
     */
    public static function authenticate($providerId, $params = null) {
        Hybrid_Logger::info("Enter Hybrid_Auth::authenticate( $providerId )");
        if (!Hybrid_Auth::storage()->get("hauth_session.$providerId.is_logged_in")) {
// if user not connected to $providerId then try setup a new adapter and start the login process for this provider
            Hybrid_Logger::info("Hybrid_Auth::authenticate( $providerId ), User not connected to the provider. Try to authenticate..");
            $provider_adapter = Hybrid_Auth::setup($providerId, $params);
            $provider_adapter->login();
        } else {
// else, then return the adapter instance for the given provider
            Hybrid_Logger::info("Hybrid_Auth::authenticate( $providerId ), User is already connected to this provider. Return the adapter instance.");
            return Hybrid_Auth::getAdapter($providerId);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Return the adapter instance for an authenticated provider
     *
     * @param string $providerId ID of the provider
     * @return Hybrid_Provider_Adapter
     */
    public static function getAdapter($providerId = null) {
        Hybrid_Logger::info("Enter Hybrid_Auth::getAdapter( $providerId )");
        return Hybrid_Auth::setup($providerId);
    }
    /**
     * Setup an adapter for a given provider
     *
     * @param string $providerId ID of the provider
     * @param array  $params     Adapter params
     * @return Hybrid_Provider_Adapter
     */
    public static function setup($providerId, $params = null) {
        Hybrid_Logger::debug("Enter Hybrid_Auth::setup( $providerId )", $params);
        if (!$params) {
            $params = Hybrid_Auth::storage()->get("hauth_session.$providerId.id_provider_params");
            Hybrid_Logger::debug("Hybrid_Auth::setup( $providerId ), no params given. Trying to get the stored for this provider.", $params);
        }
        if (!$params) {
            $params = array();
            Hybrid_Logger::info("Hybrid_Auth::setup( $providerId ), no stored params found for this provider. Initialize a new one for new session");
        }
        if (is_array($params) && !isset($params["hauth_return_to"])) {
            $params["hauth_return_to"] = Hybrid_Auth::getCurrentUrl();
            Hybrid_Logger::debug("Hybrid_Auth::setup( $providerId ). HybridAuth Callback URL set to: ", $params["hauth_return_to"]);
        }
# instantiate a new IDProvider Adapter
        $provider = new Hybrid_Provider_Adapter();
        $provider->factory($providerId, $params);
        return $provider;
    }
    /**
     * Check if the current user is connected to a given provider
     *
     * @param string $providerId ID of the provider
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isConnectedWith($providerId) {
        return (bool) Hybrid_Auth::storage()->get("hauth_session.{$providerId}.is_logged_in");
    }
    /**
     * Return array listing all authenticated providers
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getConnectedProviders() {
        $idps = array();
        foreach (Hybrid_Auth::$config["providers"] as $idpid => $params) {
            if (Hybrid_Auth::isConnectedWith($idpid)) {
                $idps[] = $idpid;
            }
        }
        return $idps;
    }
    /**
     * Return array listing all enabled providers as well as a flag if you are connected
     *
     * <code>
     * array(
     *   'Facebook' => array(
     *     'connected' => true
     *   )
     * )
     * </code>
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getProviders() {
        $idps = array();
        foreach (Hybrid_Auth::$config["providers"] as $idpid => $params) {
            if ($params['enabled']) {
                $idps[$idpid] = array('connected' => false);
                if (Hybrid_Auth::isConnectedWith($idpid)) {
                    $idps[$idpid]['connected'] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return $idps;
    }
    /**
     * A generic function to logout all connected provider at once
     * @return void
     */
    public static function logoutAllProviders() {
        $idps = Hybrid_Auth::getConnectedProviders();
        foreach ($idps as $idp) {
            $adapter = Hybrid_Auth::getAdapter($idp);
            $adapter->logout();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Utility function, redirect to a given URL with php header or using javascript location.href
     *
     * @param string $url  URL to redirect to
     * @param string $mode PHP|JS
     */
    public static function redirect($url, $mode = "PHP") {
        Hybrid_Logger::info("Enter Hybrid_Auth::redirect( $url, $mode )");
// Ensure session is saved before sending response, see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/12341
        if ((PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50400 && PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE === session_status()) || (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50400 && isset($_SESSION) && session_id())) {
            session_write_close();
        }
        if ($mode == "PHP") {
            header("Location: $url");
        } elseif ($mode == "JS") {
            echo '<html>';
            echo '<head>';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'function redirect(){ window.top.location.href="' . $url . '"; }';
            echo '</script>';
            echo '</head>';
            echo '<body onload="redirect()">';
            echo 'Redirecting, please wait...';
            echo '</body>';
            echo '</html>';
        }
        die();
    }
    /**
     * Utility function, return the current url
     *
     * @param bool $request_uri true to get $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], false for $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getCurrentUrl($request_uri = true) {
        if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
            return '';
        }
        $protocol = 'http://';
        if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1 ))
            || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'))
        {
            $protocol = 'https://';
        }
        $url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        if ($request_uri) {
            $url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        } else {
            $url .= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        }
// return current url
        return $url;
    }
}
```